# ERROR in getting setup.py and project.toml

Tags: python, pip

I am getting the following error using `pip` 
The error:

```
pip install -r requirements-dev.txt .
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Obtaining file:///home/yashashwi
ERROR: file:///home/yashashwi does not appear to be a Python project: neither 'setup.py' nor 'pyproject.toml' found.
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
ERROR: Directory '.' is not installable. Neither 'setup.py' nor 'pyproject.toml' found.
```

Comment: Hello. Missing some key info needed in order to offer any help. What version of Ubuntu? What is the exact command you ran that produced this error?

Comment: I am using 22.04, also the command is ```pip install -e .
pip install -r requirements-dev.txt .``` @David

Comment: Since 22.04 does not exist yet it is off topic. Sorry.

Comment: did anybody get solution?

Comment: @maths-is-fun please can you attach your `requirements-dev.txt`

Comment: Sorry to update so late but its fixed now somehow

Answer (score 1):

This error has nothing to do with the ubuntu version. As the error clearly states, pip cannot find any `setup.py` nor `pyproject.toml` in the current directory (you are passing it with `.`). Just remove that dot from the end of your command:
`pip install -r requirements-dev.txt`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it is now fixed.